# Is it possible to see data stored in SQLite using javascript in Cross-Platform Apps?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, sqlite

I am developing a **Cross-Platform Application** for **iOS** using **AngularJS**.
I am using **SQLite** to store my data.
Now I want to see my data stored in Database.
So is it possible to see data stored in SQLite using javascript?
just like **phpMyAdmin in PHP**?
**I don't want to retrieve** I just want to see the database.
I can tool or extension or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, Accessing data directly through Javascript wouldnt be advised as it is open to security risks.

You would be better creating a controller to validate the incoming data and handle database transactions and return a response

Comment: I want to see the database in the development mode. And I don't want to retrieve just see values in database

Comment: but you would have to retrieve the values to see them?

Comment: well I need functionalities  like "SQL Management Studio" or "PHPMyAdmin"